# Language is not changed in Magento

Tags: magento2

My current Magento 2.2.0 site in displayed in English, I have changed the language to Danish in the admin panel but that has not changed anything. The option for Danish language comes standard with Magento.

I followed this guide: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-danish-language-pack

But that has not changed anything either.

How do I change the frontend language on a Magento 2.2.0 site? This is really frustrating

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache and running the command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy da_DK  and have you created the Danish store view in admin ?

Comment: Hi, I've cleaned my cache, the deploy command required me to use the -f option which I then did. I haven't created a Danish store view in admin since Danish is the only language the website should be able to be viewed in, so I just changed the locale to Danish. Is that not enough? Is it required to create a seperate view? Thanks.

Comment: If Danish is the only language the website is using, then you don't need to create a separate store view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your language pack work, you should keep the language pack files inside the language code specific library. Then only it will work.

In your case, the Danish language pack should be inside the da_DK folder. It should follow the folder structure like below.

```
Your-Magento-Root-Folder/app/i18n/your-name-space-in-small-letters/da_DK/
```

This will fix your problem. Make sure after following this folder structure, clear cache and run the static content deploy command.

Comment: I'm using Magento 2.2.0, there is not a i18n folder in app folder, I currently using a Magento default theme called Luma, there is a i18n folder in /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n

Comment: You should create the i18n folder inside the app folder. By default, the i18n folder is not there. :) and dont worry about the theme. This will work. I have reproduced your issue and verified in my local.

Comment: Ahh okay, I'll try that

Comment: No, it's not the name of the theme. Its the custom name space of your language packs. If you are using mageplaza's language pack, then it would be mageplaza.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, should I remove the older incorrect installation that I did earlier? Where I used composer?

Comment: No need to remove, just place the files inside app/i18n/mageplaza/da_DK/

Comment: I've just installed the language the way you said by creating those folders, and that works great! But I don't know where Composer did the automatic installation and I'd like to remove those unneeded files, that is what I meant :).

Comment: No problem. There are no unwanted files you need to remove. It's fine. Have a good time :)